# Ambient occlusion is not in world properties

Tags: cycles-render-engine, ambient-occlusion

Ambient acclusion is not in my world properties. there isn't a check box and the distance for it. I saw blenderguru's tutorial there was a check option and distance for it however there is the option in layer properties>passes>light for check ambient occlusion but no distance option.

Comment: The settings for ambient occlusion are only available if you're using eevee as your render engine.
The "passes" setting is for rendering a 'pass' (an image) with the AO information, not for setting the AO parameters.

Comment: Are you using Eevee or Cycles for rendering? - That option is noly there if you select Eevee.

Comment: @AlexandreMarcati thank you I got it.

Comment: @JohnEason I am using cycles thank you for letting me know.